# How to create an own code action category in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm writing a vscode extension where I use some code actions.
I would like to group my actions within an own category.

Currently, when I hit with some text selected the "lightbulb" icon I got
actions grouped under "Extract" and "Surround With".

How could I create a new/own section and add my actions to it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, but you can upvote this GH issue (hurry though...):

[Allow extensions to contribute code action menu groups](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/194803)